# Python plot a list of lists with different number of elements

Tags: python, list, matplotlib

I am giving an example of what I am trying to plot.

```
big_list = [[12,13,-12],[1,5,9,10,12],[-1,-2]]
plt.plot(big_list.index,big_list)
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (31906,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you want to plot all sub-lists on the same figure:

```
for list in big_list:
    plt.plot(list)
```

If not please comment. It's not clear to me what you want you your x axis.

**Update** based on comment:

In this case you can do:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
for i,list in enumerate(big_list):
    plt.scatter([i]*len(list), list)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
```

[image]

Comment: This looks good. The problem with it is, all elements of a sub-list are not drawn on a same index. Instead, a range of index equal to the number of elements is considered. This is not what I wanted. I want all the elements of a sub-list on same index.

Comment: Please see my update for this case (or use boxplots as in your answer).

Comment: This looks good than box plots I thought. I shall take it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error, I found the box plots is what I wanted. I have three sub-lists and box plot produces three indexes on x-axis and produces a box on y-axis in proportionate to the values in the sub-list.

My code:

```
plt.boxplot(big_list)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]